# Openlayer map not visible i have install npm sucessfully

Tags: openlayers-3

[Uncaught SyntaxError: Private field '#map' must be declared in an enclosing class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HynHV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Suspect that npm is broken for openlayers (or openlayers is broken for npm)... it worked this morning until I did an npm update and now its all broken and stupid...

I had upgraded to npm 7.19.1 which npm cheerfully chirped about - I downgraded back to the npm 6.14.13 that comes with FC33. I'm also still learning to avoid installing npm modules with "sudo"...

Upgrading to 7.x npm start/build demanded that  be used - and once you use it the .css in the example index.html from openlayers examlpes gets broken right at "#map" or ".map"...